# How to repeat a row for each value of its corresponding columns items

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (str)1 | (str)3 | (str)34 |
| (str)2 | (str)4 | (str)2 |

to

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| (str)1 | (str)3 |
| (str)1 | (str)34 |
| (str)2 | (str)4 |
| (str)2 | (str)2 |

Comment: `df.set_index('col1').stack()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `melt` then `sort_values`

```
out = df.melt('col1').sort_values('col1')#.drop('variable',1)
Out[426]: 
     col1 variable    value
0  (str)1     col2   (str)3
2  (str)1     col3  (str)34
1  (str)2     col2   (str)4
3  (str)2     col3   (str)2
```